# FireDAC ApplyUpdates and transaction control

Tags: transactions, firebird2.5, firedac, dbexpress, c++builder-xe7

I am converting application written in DBExpress to use new FireDAC components. The basic things like opening the query, changing filter or ordering, displaying in grid are working correctly. But I am surprised that some functions behave differently in comparison to dbexpress and I cant seem to comprehend it.

My application contains database editor. When user opens the editor new 
transaction is started by calling method `TFDConnection::StartTransaction`. When the user clicks on OK button, the active transaction is committed and editor closes.

In editor I use two queries to edit records. In first query I manually compose SQL update command (like "`update TEST set NAME='some name' where ID=1234`") and execute it. So far so good.

Second query is connected to `TDBAdvGrid` (equivalent of `TDBGrid` from *TMS Software company*) and have `CachedUpdates = true`. If I change some record in that grid I call `TFDQuery::Post` and `TFDQuery::ApplyUpdates`.

Whats weird calling `TFDQuery::ApplyUpdates` commits not only pending changes in this specific query, but all queries connected to instance of `TFDConnection`. I thought that calling of `ApplyUpdates` should issue SQL update calls but should not interfere with transaction control.

I want to give the user option to reject all changes made by him in database editor window. How to do it correctly ? Should I postpone call to `ApplyUpdates` to time when closing window ? What is then the purpose of `TFDQuery::CommitUpdates` and `TFDConnection::Commit` if all that is necessary is the call of `TFDQuery::ApplyUpdates`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set TFDConnection::TxOptions::StopOptions::xoIfCmdsInactive to false. This will also disable TFDConnection::TxOptions::AutoCommit option and application can controls transactions by itself.